# Dropping one category for regularized linear models

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, regularization, one-hot-encoding

While reviewing the sklearn's OneHotEncoder documentation (attached below) I noticed that when applying regularization (e.g., lasso, ridge, etc.) it is not recommended to drop the first category. While I understand why dropped the first category prevents collinearity, I am unsure why it is needed for regularized regression. Wouldn't this this add an additional dimension that will need to be regularized?

> drop{‘first’, ‘if_binary’}

> Specifies a methodology to use to drop one of the categories per
> feature. This is useful in situations where perfectly collinear
> features cause problems, such as when feeding the resulting data into
> a neural network or an unregularized regression.
> **However, dropping one category breaks the symmetry of the original
> representation and can therefore induce a bias in downstream models,
> for instance for penalized linear classification or regression models.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do linear regression you have to leave out one column as it's a singular matrix and hence columns are linearly dependent and we cannot calculate the inverse.

But when you do regularization it take cares of singularity. `The matrix is almost surely nonsingular`. Hence we don't need to drop a column and if you drop different columns from each feature it could lead to different prediction as it would lead to bias.

Refer [this](https://inmachineswetrust.com/posts/drop-first-columns/).